# Change field without changing field separator in $0

Tags: awk, field, separator

When any field is assigned to in AWK, `$0` is recomputed and the original field separators are replaced with the output field separator (`OFS`). But I want the field separators in `$0` to remain unchanged when I change the fields. My input field separator (`FS`) is a regular expression, so simply making the output file separator the same as the input file separator won't do.

Is there any way to change the fields without changing the field separators in `$0`?

EDIT:
My input field separator is `FS = "([^[:digit:]\\.,]|^)+0*[\\.,]?0*";`.
My script inspects the numbers on the left side of the equals sign and changes the numbers on right side accordingly for each line of input (to be exact, it finds and corrects the number of significant figures). For instance, given the input

```
50g * 10 = 500g
0.030L+1.12L=1.150L
```

my script should output

```
50g * 10 = 50E+1g
0.030L+1.12L=1.2L
```

, but due to the original field separators being replaced as I change the field that is the number on the right side of the equals sign, it instead outputs

```
50 10 50E+1
30 1.12 1.2
```

Comment: Provide an input example and let us know how you want it to work.

Comment: `tmp=$0; sub(/.../,"&",tmp); $0=tmp`? Or GNU awk `split($0,arr, FS, seps)` and the separators are safe in `seps`? Untested as you provided no sample data.

Comment: @Inian, I've added example input and what the corresponding output should look like vs. what it actually looks like. Should I post the script itself as well? (~30 lines)

Comment: Post a **Minimal** script that demonstrates **the problem you are asking for help with**. We don't need to see whatever larger script you were running when you came across this problem. Just post a [mcve] that demonstrates **this problem**.

Comment: @JamesBrown the gawk split seems to do what I want, but I'd rather keep it POSIX compliant. I guess I could just use sub to find and replace the original number with the number produced by my script, but handling duplicate numbers would be a little nasty.

Comment: No. do not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the details of your question but to change a field without changing the field separators you use a regexp on the whole record. Look:

```
$ echo 'a;b;c;d' | awk -F';' '{$3="X"}1'
a b X d

$ echo 'a;b;c;d' | awk 'match($0,/^([^;]*;){2}/){head=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); tail=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH); sub(/^[^;]*/,"",tail); $0 = head "X" tail } 1'
a;b;X;d
```

Yes, it's more code but it does a string replacement without changing FS to OFS. It can be done more concisely with GNU awk but since you wanted POSIX...

The alternative if your FS can't be negated is a loop with match()+substr().

If you edit your question to include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with concise, testable sample input and expected output then you can get more help.

Comment: So I guess there isn't a way to change a field and keep the field separators. I think the cleanest workaround in my case will be the match and substr loop you mentioned, but I'm glad we got a few other suggestions that whoever might have the same question but a very different script can make use of. Thank you!